# Why jest config's unmockedModulePathPatterns does not unmock axios?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, axios

I have an application where I am trying to differentiate integration tests from unit tests. This difference is made through two types of files suffixes `.ispec.ts` for integration and `.test.ts` for  unit.

Another difference between them is that unit tests shouldn't access the network, for that I've setup a mock for `axios` on `<rootDir>/__mocks__/axios.ts` which prevents that behavior successfully. For integration tests however, I'd like to go over the network and `axios` should keep it's normal operation.

To prevent axios from being mocked on `ispec` files, I am adding the following line in all the files:

```js
// anyFile.ispec.ts
imports (...)

jest.unmock('axios'); // this line required in every .ispec file

describe(...)
```

Reading the jest documentation, I came across the following option [`unmockedModulePathPatterns`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#unmockedmodulepathpatterns-array-string) where as the name suggests, defined modules on this array will be unmocked by the jest cli.

So I've changed my jest configurations for:

```js
// jest.unit.js
module.exports = {
  testRegex: '/__tests__/.+\\.test\\.ts$'
};
```

and

```js
// jest.integration.js
module.exports = {
  testRegex: '/__tests__/.+\\.ispec\\.ts$',
  unmockedModulePathPatterns: ['axios']
}
```

To my surprise, after removing the line `jest.unmock('axios')` from my `ispec` files and running `jest --config ./jest.integration.js` still makes use of the mocked `axios` which is not my intention.

Did I miss the point of `unmockedModulePathPatterns` or is it a bug on jest configuration? I also tried setting [`automock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#automock-boolean) to `false`, but the behavior is still the same.